# Can't save data from firestore event listener

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

Hello guys and thanks you for your time.

So in my app, I'm trying to fetch data in real time from my firestore database with a SnapshotListener and then save it in a global variable.
The fetching itself works fine, but when I try to save it into an array it fails. It says the array is empty afterwards.

Can you guys explain me what's wrong since I'm still starting on this firestore thing?

Here's the part of the code I think is helpfull:

```
// Get barbershops nearby from google firestore
        MainActivity.db.collection("barbershops")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                            Log.d(TAG, doc.getId() + " => " + doc.getData());
                            Barbershop bbs = doc.toObject(Barbershop.class);
                            barbershops.add(bbs);
                        }
                    }
                });

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Set up the recycler view
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        // use a linear layout manager
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(barbershops, getContext(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
```

and then I also have a global variable:

`private ArrayList<Barbershop> barbershops;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`addSnapshotListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback is invoked some time later with the results of the query.  That means `barbershops` won't be populated right away.  It's not clear from your question what "the array is empty afterwards" actually means, but if you try to use `barbershops` before the callback has been invoked, you will not see the data from those documents.  You should only use that list after the callback is invoked.

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you give me an example? How can I do it?

Comment: So, what should I change in there? I added some code